# Connect to oracle database from developer suite

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

What I am trying to establish:

- use Developer Suite 10g to develop a simple local oracle database on a windows 7 machine

What I did:

- installed **Oracle Developer Suite 10g**
- installed **Oracle database 11g** (because DevSuite does not have a db)
- set `ORACLE_HOME` to database 11g's home path
- restarted `OracleService` from services.msc
- started a `listener` from `Net Configuration Assistant`

Now I'm trying to use `Oracle Forms Builder` from `Developer Suite` to connect to the database, however I am getting `TNS: Could not resolve the connect identifier`, because the database and the DeveloperSuite are two different applications with two different `tnsnames.ora`.

I can connect to the database from its own `sqlPlus` but how can I connect to the database from DevSuite's applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out finally:

Override the file `tnsnames.ora` from `DeveloperSuite\NETWORK\ADMIN` with the one from `database\product\11.2.0\db_home\hs\admin`